# Deleted workspace the wrong way

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have deleted some workspaces by deleting the complete workspace folders in my home folder. Just right mouse click and delete.

Now when I open a terminal I get multiple messages:

```
bash: /home/lauran/ur5_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/ur5_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/robot_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/lauran/robot_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

I don't use these workspaces anymore but I've read that I should have deleted my workspaces more properly.
Is there a way where i can fix these errors so that there won't a situation where these deleted workspaces cause any problems?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275230/deleted-workspace-the-wrong-way/) by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a way where i can fix these errors so that there won't a situation where these deleted workspaces cause any problems?

Try opening the file `/home/lauran/.bashrc` in a text editor (gedit fi) and scroll to the end. Most likely you have a number of `source /home/lauran/../devel/setup.bash` lines there.

Remove (or comment) those and save the file. Open a new terminal. The errors should now be gone.

> I don't use these workspaces anymore but I've read that I should have deleted my workspaces more properly.

Workspaces are just directories with files, so removing them is exactly the same as you would with any other directories and / or files.

I wouldn't know of a more "proper way".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lauran](https://answers.ros.org/users/32528/lauran/) on 2017-11-07**:
The problem has been resolved, thank you